# Inner join linq to webgrid

Tags: linq

Is it possible to use inner join on tables with linq, and put the value in a list so i can place it in a webgrid?

Little code i want to add another table to the linq and fill the rest so i can show it on the view !

```
        List<vakantieList> Freedayslist = new List<vakantieList>();
        /*Create instance of entity model*/
        GemeenteLeerdanEntities2 db = new GemeenteLeerdanEntities2();

        var result = (from data in db.Freedays 
                              select data);
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Freedayslist.Add(new vakantieList
            {
                FreeDaysID = item.FreeDaysID,
                BSN = item.BSN,
                FirstName = item.FirstName,
                LastName = item.LastName,
                TotalDays = item.TotalDays,
                DaysUsed = item.DaysUsed,
                DaysRemaining = item.DaysRemaining,
                PersonalID = item.PersonalID,
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Inner joins are possible in LINQ, have a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.90).aspx).

But, in your case, you don't need an inner join, you simply need to fill your custom list, and you can directly do that in LINQ query without separate `foreach` loop.
Try this:-

```
List<vakantieList> = (from data in db.Freedays
             select new vakantieList
             {
                FreeDaysID = data.FreeDaysID,
                BSN = data.BSN,
                FirstName = data.FirstName,
                LastName = data.LastName,
                TotalDays = data.TotalDays,
                DaysUsed = data.DaysUsed,
                DaysRemaining = data.DaysRemaining,
                PersonalID = data.PersonalID,
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Do i need to add the second table in the same list also and then add it to the webgrid ?

Comment: @OktayAltay - Where is your second table? You didn't mentioned. Yes you can join both and fill your custom list `vakantieList`.